# Finding all invertible square matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, algebra

I want to write a function where given the two integers "n" and "p", it generates all the invertible matrices of order n where the elements come from {0,1,...,p-1}.
I have the following code :

```
import itertools 
import numpy as np 

def invertible_matrices(n, p):
    invertibleMatrices = set()
    # generates all the possible matrices
    x = [y for y in range(p)]
    a = [j for j in itertools.product(x, repeat=n)]
    b = {k for k in itertools.product(a, repeat=n)}
    for each in b:
        if np.linalg.det(each) != 0:
            invertibleMatrices.add(each)
    return invertibleMatrices
```

for `n=2` and `p=2` it works fine but for `n=2` and `p=3` I get `50` while the answer is `48`.
any help would be appreciated.

p.s: if you're familiar with group theory I'm trying to find all the elements of [GL(n, p)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_group#Over_finite_fields) (the general linear group over a finite field with p elements)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you want the determinant modulo p (which is the determinant in the context of GL(n,p), i.e. over the finite field with p elements).

```
if not np.isclose((np.linalg.det(each)+1)%p,1):
    invertibleMatrices.add(each)
```

Note: the +1 is to avoid wrap around of small numerical errors.

Comment: I feel stupid for not realising that point for a whole semester. Thank you so much.

Comment: If I understand correctly - this is because "invertible" in GL(n,p) means "invertible over the finite field with p elements", whereas "det !=0"  means "invertible over R^n"

Comment: (I've edited to explain that bit, revert or re-edit if I got it wrong)

Comment: @ItamarMushkin I think it would be more correct to say that the (actual) det is a polynomial in the matrix elements which are from the finite field. So, technically, the det can only take values between 0 and p-1.

Comment: Or more concisely - that the det modulo p is the det in the finite field (all the rest is implicit)

Answer (score 2):

Use inspect_matrix() for debugging, get_invertible_matrices() for using a set comprehension to determine all invertible matrices, and get_determinant_1_matrices() to get the ones with determinant 1:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np


def inspect_matrix(n, p):
    """Examine a single, square matrix."""
    a = list(itertools.product(list(range(p)), repeat=n))
    matrices = {k
                for k in itertools.product(a, repeat=n)
               }
    matrix = next(iter(matrices))  # Inspect one of the matrices
    determinant = np.linalg.det(matrix)
    print(f"{matrix = }\n{determinant = }")
    print(f"inverse = {(inverse:=np.linalg.inv(matrix))}") if determinant != 0.0 else print("Matrix is not invertible")
    return inverse 


def get_invertible_matrices(n, p):
    """Generates all the possible matrices."""
    a = list(itertools.product(list(range(p)), repeat=n))
    invertible_matrices = {k
                           for k in itertools.product(a, repeat=n)
                           if not np.isclose((np.linalg.det(k) + 1) % p, 1)
                           }
    print(f"{len(invertible_matrices) = }")
    return invertible_matrices


def get_determinant_1_matrices(n, p):
    """Generates all the square matrices with determinant 1."""
    a = list(itertools.product(list(range(p)), repeat=n))
    if p==2:
            det_1_matrices = {k
                              for k in itertools.product(a, repeat=n)
                              if np.isclose((np.linalg.det(k))%p,1)
                              }
    else:
            det_1_matrices = {k
                              for k in itertools.product(a, repeat=n)
                              if np.isclose((np.linalg.det(k)+1)%p,2)
                              }
    print(f"{len(det_1_matrices) = }")
    return det_1_matrices


def main():
    print(get_invertible_matrices(n=2, p=2))
    print(get_invertible_matrices(n=2, p=3))
    print(get_determinant_1_matrices(n=2, p=2))
    print(get_determinant_1_matrices(n=2, p=3))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

returns:

```
len(invertible_matrices) = 6
{((1, 1), (0, 1)), ((1, 0), (0, 1)), ((1, 0), (1, 1)), ((0, 1), (1, 0)), ((0, 1), (1, 1)), ((1, 1), (1, 0))}
len(invertible_matrices) = 48
{((1, 0), (0, 1)), ((1, 2), (0, 2)), ((2, 1), (1, 0)), ((0, 2), (2, 0)), ((0, 1), (2, 0)), ((1, 1), (1, 0)), ((2, 1), (1, 1)), ((2, 2), (2, 0)), ((1, 1), (2, 1)), ((1, 2), (1, 0)), ((2, 1), (2, 2)), ((2, 0), (0, 2)), ((1, 2), (1, 1)), ((2, 2), (0, 2)), ((1, 0), (0, 2)), ((1, 1), (1, 2)), ((1, 2), (2, 2)), ((2, 1), (0, 1)), ((1, 1), (0, 1)), ((0, 2), (1, 0)), ((0, 1), (1, 0)), ((2, 0), (2, 1)), ((0, 2), (2, 1)), ((2, 2), (1, 0)), ((0, 1), (2, 1)), ((1, 2), (0, 1)), ((0, 2), (1, 1)), ((2, 0), (1, 1)), ((0, 1), (1, 1)), ((2, 2), (2, 1)), ((2, 0), (2, 2)), ((0, 2), (2, 2)), ((2, 1), (2, 0)), ((0, 1), (2, 2)), ((1, 0), (2, 1)), ((1, 0), (1, 1)), ((1, 1), (2, 0)), ((2, 0), (1, 2)), ((0, 2), (1, 2)), ((0, 1), (1, 2)), ((1, 0), (2, 2)), ((2, 0), (0, 1)), ((1, 2), (2, 0)), ((2, 2), (1, 2)), ((2, 1), (0, 2)), ((1, 0), (1, 2)), ((2, 2), (0, 1)), ((1, 1), (0, 2))}
len(det_1_matrices) = 6
{((0, 1), (1, 1)), ((0, 1), (1, 0)), ((1, 0), (0, 1)), ((1, 0), (1, 1)), ((1, 1), (0, 1)), ((1, 1), (1, 0))}
len(det_1_matrices) = 24
{((2, 2), (0, 2)), ((0, 2), (1, 2)), ((1, 1), (0, 1)), ((1, 2), (2, 2)), ((2, 1), (2, 0)), ((1, 0), (0, 1)), ((2, 0), (2, 2)), ((2, 1), (1, 1)), ((1, 1), (2, 0)), ((1, 0), (2, 1)), ((1, 2), (0, 1)), ((1, 2), (1, 0)), ((2, 0), (0, 2)), ((1, 0), (1, 1)), ((1, 1), (1, 2)), ((0, 2), (1, 0)), ((0, 1), (2, 2)), ((0, 2), (1, 1)), ((0, 1), (2, 1)), ((2, 0), (1, 2)), ((0, 1), (2, 0)), ((2, 2), (2, 1)), ((2, 2), (1, 0)), ((2, 1), (0, 2))}
```

Comment: Why do we need `x=[y for y in range(p)]`? Won't it work with `a=[j for j in itertools.product(list(range(p)), repeat=n)`?

Comment: thanks a lot. I'm very new to numpy and I know `np.isclose(a,b)` is used to compare two matrices but I can't understand how does it work here? and if I want to change the condition from "invertible matrices" to "matrices with determinant equal to 1" how should I change your set comprehension?

Comment: @ladypary I reworked the code, so you can more easily get the determinant==1, or the invertible matrices, just by updating your calls in the new main function.

Comment: @Gustav Rasmussen thanks a lot. since this one should generate all the elements of  SL(n, p) = {A ∈ GL(n, p) | det A = 1}. I think we should use determinant modulo p =1. I tried changing the above code and it works fine for `n=2,p=2` and  `n=2,p=3` but for `n=2,p=5`  I get `86` matrices but it should be `120`

Comment: I fixed it for """Generates all the square matrices with determinant 1."""

Comment: @ladypary nice job! I added a helper function in the top, inspect_matrix(), that you can use for testing out one matrix at a time.